# Change color theme for Beamer

Tags: beamer, color, themes

this question is indeed trivial, but I haven't found any answer to it online. I'm for the first time using the Beamer environment to make a presentation. I'm using the Cambridge US theme, but I want to change the color of the theme to structure, as seen in this [example](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/individual/CambridgeUS-structure-default.html). I found quite a lot of information on how to change the color of specific elements within the Beamer environment, but I simply want to change the color of the entire theme.

The reason for this is I don't like the combination of the red general theme and the blue graphics for itemize.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Introduction}
 Blablabla
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX: I think you may find some useful information in [What are structural elements? Customizing the mechnism of beamer color theme](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130464/13304).

Comment: See section 17.1.2 of the [beamer manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer): Complete Color Themes